# Packaging Adobe AIR As .APK For Android

Tags: android, apache-flex, air, air-android

I have a simple "Hello World" style .air application.

How do I turn it into an .APK that can be run in the Android emulator?

I am using Adobe **Flex Builder 3** to create the .AIR file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, the prior responder is correct, you cannot use Flex Builder 3 (or Flash Builder 4 even) for this purpose. I recommend you download the free preview release of Flash Builder "Burrito" that was posted on Labs around MAX in October http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/flashbuilder_burrito/. This version of the IDE includes a preview of the mobile workflow you will need to create mobile applications using Flex "Hero" mobile SDK.

In terms of porting your existing appliation, while you can run MX (Halo) components on Android, it is not recommended as they are not optimized for mobile in terms of performance or for handling things like touch. The Spark mobile components included in the "Hero" SDK you will get with the preview of Flash Builder "Burrito" have mobile skins optimized to perform better on Android as well as handling touch inputs.

Answer (score 1):

Flash Builder 3 does not support creating .APK files. You will have to use the ADT command line tool that comes with the AIR SDK. You can find a step-by-step guide to doing that [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WSfffb011ac560372f-5d0f4f25128cc9cd0cb-7ffb.html) and [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WS901d38e593cd1bac25d3d8c712b2d86751e-8000.html).

Answer (score 1):

@Joshua hi use adobe flex4.5.it provides or a support to make .apk file for android app.

Answer (score 0):

You can use also IntelliJ IDEA for deploying application to Android. IDEA has amazing refactoring tools and great handling for Flex/ActionScript, it's AIR Mobile Deployment maybe not that attractive visually like Flash Builder have but it does great job.